# Refreshing html table after ajax success

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When we perform destructive operations on database tables (insert/update/delete) using ajax, the DOM has to reflect this change. I see two commonly used approaches.

- When the destructive database operation succeeds, manipulate the rows in the html table to reflect the change
- When the destructive database operation succeeds, refresh the html table by making another ajax request

Suppose users A and B are accessing a table of 5 rows. Then A deletes the first row while B deletes the second row. With the DOM manipulation approach, A will not see that the second row is deleted while B will not see that the first row is deleted. This problem can be eliminated by the refresh approach, but both users can only see the full updates when they themselves perform an operation.

Which is the best approach?

Comment: Option B is better for exactly the reason you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem cannot be eliminated by simple "refresh" approach(option 2).

Let's say both A and B viewing the table. Now A deleted a row, if you refresh the page of A it'll be only updated on A's view window. But code running on B will not be aware at the moment of the fact that the row is deleted. He will see the update only after he delete one row as per option 2 or obviously make a browser refresh.

One quick solution is to refresh the table data by using Ajax request in a fixed interval. For ex: 5 seconds.

To make the table reflect truly real-time data of the database at any moment for every user you have to use websocket. For this you need both real-time server and client.

You can implement a portion or feature of your entire web application in something like [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) to make that portion real-time while keeping the other portion as is using your existing technology stack.

Comment: thanks. I am curious, why do people keep using the above 2 approaches and not using websocket every time?